# Travel from Lyon to Geneva Airport (French side)

Tags: trains, france, car-rentals, geneva, gva

I'll be in Lyon for a few days in June (taking a train from Paris) and planning to rent a car in Lyon. It sounds like I can drive from Lyon to the French side of the Geneva airport and drop off the car there. Is that possible?

Should I take the train instead? My flight is at 12:30 p.m. on a Tuesday.

Comment: Do you have any particular preference/criteria (time/cost/convenience)? Any particular reason to go to the French side of the airport beyond dropping the car there?

Comment: It's to avoid paying the the motorway vignette, since I'm only entering the country to reach the airport. I've had a hard time finding trains that will take me to the GVA airport from Lyon in time for the flight.

Comment: Then you need to go through Bellegarde, Saint-Genis and Ferney-Voltaire or Meyrin. It's a nice road actually and probably only 15 min longer, you just need to plan accordingly.

Comment: To follow up, the drive was pretty easy. The only issue was Google Maps placed the Sixt car rental location outside the airport, when it was actually located in the airport.

Comment: For completeness, it's perhaps worth reporting that, uh, folks have been known to get away with **not having a vignette** for the tiny drive from the border to the airport.  But it would be very hard to do this unless you have a really local vibe and familiarity with the scene.

Comment: The motorway vignette is only required for Swiss motorways. It isn't needed if you can take a route to the airport that avoids motorways in Switzerland.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk the airport is immediately adjacent to a motorway, but it is also accessible without using that motorway. Coming from Lyon, you can ask for directions to CERN, then continue east-southeast on the Route de Meyrin. Google considers the Swiss motorway vignette to be a toll, so if you ask to avoid tolls it will give you directions from CERN to the airport that avoid the motorway at a cost of 1 extra minute of predicted driving time. The predicted time to CERN from Lyon is the same as the predicted time to GVA using the motorway, so the CERN route is 11 minutes longer altogether.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually the simplest answer to your question is Yes.

The airport of Geneva, although situated in Switzerland, is an international airport and has a French section. It can be accessed from France without passing the Swiss customs, through a special road ([route douanière](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/75689695)).

There are car rentals at the French section of the Airport, for exemple [Sixt](http://www.sixt.fr/location-voiture/france/ferney-voltaire/geneve-aeroport-secteur-france/). This means you can rent a car in any Sixt Agency in Lyon (there is one at Part-Dieu train station), and drop the car at the French section of the airport of Genève, that you access via this road exclusively.

Here is an excerpt of the GVA agency of Sixt's web page:

> Notre agence se trouve au niveau 1 dans le hall des arrivées. Le parking P20 se situe au rez de chaussée du bâtiment abrittant (sic) le secteur France.
>   […]
>   Le retour de votre véhicule doit s'effectuer au parking P20 au Secteur France de l'aéroport de Genève à l’adresse ci-dessous: Route douanière 01216 Ferney Voltaire Coordonnés GPS: N 46°23.97 E 11°84.08

There are other car rental companies: [Europcar](https://applications.europcar.com/stationgeolocation/CDN/files/GVFT01.pdf), [Avis](http://www.avis.com/car-rental/location/details.ac?LOCATIONCODE=GGV), [Hertz](https://www.hertz.com/rentacar/location/france/geneva/GVAT52?origin=Homepage) for example.

As a side note, conversely, the Basel-Mulhouse airport is located in France, but is accessible from Switzerland via a similar road.

Warning: I don't know whether your car rental contract will allow you to drive on Swiss roads, so if that's not the case, beware that accessing the airport only via French roads can be a bit long, because [Pays de Gex](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/3141128) is almost an enclave due to the Jura mountains. You can count on your hands the roads that connect that area to the rest of the French territory, and therefore you can experience traffic jams when going there via Bellegarde.

If you want to go to Geneva by train it seems to be difficult: you'll have to board train TER 17601 from Lyon to Grenoble at 06:08 then TER 96608 from Grenoble to Geneva at 07:54 (21 minutes for transfer at Grenoble), you arrive at Genève at 10:00. 4 hours train for a short trip is really unexpected. There are Eurolines buses that depart from Lyon at 08:30 and arrive at Geneva at 11:30 on the timetable, but that's too late to catch your plane.

Comment: Actually, whether you need the Swiss motorway “vignette” or not is completely unrelated to which side of the airport you are going to. The most important thing is *not* to follow the directions for Geneva on the motorway coming from Lyon.

Comment: @Annoyed, you're right. I was underlining that you don't necessarily drive on Swiss roads in order to access the French side of the airport. I am not sure that the car rental contract makes it possible to drive on foreign roads, and maybe the car rental companies can provide a vehicle that already has the vignette stuck? Since the vignette is attached to the vehicle I don't know.

Answer (score 6):

It's certainly doable. If you have a French rental car, you will need to either leave the motorway in Bellegarde-sur-Valserine and go to Ferney-Voltaire using the secondary road network or buy a CHF 40 motorway vignette for Switzerland as the car most likely will not have one. Train is also quite convenient but goes to the Swiss side, the duration of the journey from Lyon should be more-or-less similar. Within the airport, you can switch sides easily if you need to.

Do check which car hire companies are present in the French sector, some only have a desk on the Swiss side. You should also probably check in advance what they charge for dropping off the car in the French sector but in principle it should be a regular surcharge similar to what you would pay to drop it off somewhere else in France.

If you need to completely avoid going through Switzerland to reach the French side of the airport, it will be more difficult. You won't be able to take the train but could take a bus. With the car, you will need to pay attention to the directions; road signs and navigation devices would most likely bring you to the airport through Switzerland.

Comment: I'm not opposed to going through Switzerland, but not sure how to get there in time for the flight. Trains seem to be leaving in the afternoon from Lyon.

Answer (score 3):

If you decide to rent a car, beware that not all rental companies will accept taking a car in Lyon and dropping it off in Geneva (a different country). Those that do will likely charge extra for it (in addition to the motorway surcharge).

Normally 12:30 should be plenty of time to catch a train from Lyon. The [airport website](http://www.gva.ch/en/Portaldata/1/Resources/fichiers/voyageurs/TER_Lyon.pdf) mentions an 8:38 departure with a connection in Genève Cornavin, for a trip lasting a little over 2 hours, which sounds plausible. However, this page does not seem to be accurate: according to [CFF](http://fahrplan.sbb.ch/), the Lyon–Geneva train is no longer running, and the only morning connection on a weekday departs from Lyon at 7:20 and involves taking a TGV (high-speed train — but not on this stretch, with compulsory reservation and market pricing) from Bourg-en-Bresse to Geneva. This is probably due to [ongoing repair works on several lines in the northern French Alps](http://www.ter-sncf.com/Regions/rhone_alpes/Fr/Se_deplacer_en_TER/Avant_mon_voyage/Travaux/DetailsTravaux.aspx?URI=tcm%3a31-95639-1) and in the [Geneva area](http://www.cff.ch/horaire/informations-du-trafic-ferroviaire/TravauxGeneve2014.html). For the June period, the current announcement is:

- Geneva–Bellegarde trains are running with a modified schedule.
- Geneva–Lyon trains run to Saint-Julien-en-Genevois, with a bus substitution.

The CFF page states that “More precise information will be available on this page shortly.” The SNCF page promises more information 2 weeks before the beginning of each phase, which for your trip will be on 21 April. The lack of accurate information probably caused some trains not to be listed in the database even though they will end up running with only a slightly modified schedule or with a partial bus substitution.

You may want to put off planning until more information is available. I expect that there will be a reasonable train or train+bus connection that will get you there in time. You may also want to research [bus alternatives](http://www.gva.ch/en/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-69/). The most plausible connection would be via Annecy (there is a [9:15 bus to downtown Geneva](http://www.frossard.eu/pdf/annecy-cruseilles-geneve.pdf)), but it doesn't seem that you can get there in time from Lyon. There is a [bus](http://www.aerocar.fr/horaires/) that leaves Grenoble at 8:30 and Chambéry at 9:30 (in both cases, the bus stop is just outside the train station), arriving at Geneva airport at 10:45. [SNCF](http://www.ter-sncf.com/Regions/rhone_alpes/Fr/Se_deplacer_en_TER/Avant_mon_voyage/Plan_de_ligne/Carte_Flash.aspx) currently lists a 7:32 departue from Lyon to Chambéry, but there is no schedule for June; there is a 6:49 departure to Grenoble. Even with the track works, there will probably be a more direct connection to Geneva that doesn't involve that bus. You might also consider driving to Annecy or Chambéry and dropping off the car there to avoid Swiss motorway and international drop-off fees.

Comment: The French sector of the airport is not considered as a different country by car rental companies, that's the whole point of the question, I think. Otherwise, it's easy, you can just pay up and do what you want. (+1 for the research on the train situation)

Comment: "Normally 12:30 should be plenty of time to catch a train from Lyon", hmm, Gilles, the "Lyon -> Geneve airport" connection is the most annoying all of Europe, heh!  I don't think the person would make it?

Comment: @JoeBlow Now that the track works are over, the first morning train connection arrives at 8:54. So yes, it's definitely doable.

Comment: ah thanks @Gilles.  TBC you can now leave Lyon station (the normal one) and get to Genève actually the airport, at 0854 ?  That's great.  Do you know, when do you leave and where do you change if anywhere?  (perhaps you should update your answer!)

Comment: @JoeBlow As the connections can change from year to year, possibly even from season to season, and certainly depending on the time of day and day of week, I don't think it's worth keeping specific times updated. I'll leave the times from when the question was asked for historical purposes, a reader should obviously check current times which are easily found on the SNCF or CFF website.